# Python - unexpected shape parameter behavior in scipy genextreme fit

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, curve-fitting

I've been trying to fit the GEV distribution to some annual maximum river discharge using Scipy's stats.genextreme function, but I've found some weird behavior of the fit. Depending on how small your data is (i.e., 1e-5 vs. 1e-1), the shape parameter that is returned can be dramatically different. For example:

```
import scipy as scipy
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import genextreme as gev
from scipy.stats import gumbel_r as gumbel

#Set up arrays of values to fit curve to 
sample=np.random.rand(1,30) #Random set of decimal values 
smallVals = sample*1e-5     #Scale to smaller values 

#If the above is not creating different values, this instance of random numbers has:
bugArr = np.array([[0.25322987, 0.81952358, 0.94497455, 0.36295543, 0.72272746, 0.49482558,0.65674877, 0.40876558, 0.64952248, 0.23171052, 0.24645658, 0.35359126,0.27578928, 0.24820775, 0.69789187, 0.98876361, 0.22104156,0.40019593,0.0756707,  0.12342556, 0.3601186,  0.54137089,0.43477705, 0.44622486,0.75483338, 0.69766687, 0.1508741,  0.75428996, 0.93706003, 0.1191987]])
bugArr_small = bugArr*1e-5

#This array of random numbers gives the same shape parameter regardless 
fineArr = np.array([[0.7449611,  0.82376693, 0.32601009, 0.18544293, 0.56779629, 0.30495415,
        0.04670362, 0.88106521, 0.34013959, 0.84598841, 0.24454428, 0.57981437,
        0.57129427, 0.8857514,  0.96254429, 0.64174078, 0.33048637, 0.17124045,
        0.11512589, 0.31884749, 0.48975204, 0.87988863, 0.86898236, 0.83513966,
        0.05858769, 0.25889509, 0.13591874, 0.89106616, 0.66471263, 0.69786708]])
fineArr_small = fineArr*1e-5

#GEV fit for both arrays - shouldn't dramatically change distribution 
gev_fit      = gev.fit(sample)
gevSmall_fit = gev.fit(smallVals)

gevBug      = gev.fit(bugArr)
gevSmallBug = gev.fit(bugArr_small)

gevFine      = gev.fit(fineArr)
gevSmallFine = gev.fit(fineArr_small)
```

I get the following output for the GEV parameters estimated for the bugArr/bugArr_small and fineArr/fineArr_small:

```
Known bug array
Random values:         (0.12118250540401079, 0.36692231766996053, 0.23142400358716353)
Random values scaled:  (-0.8446554391074808, 3.0751769299431084e-06, 2.620390405092363e-06)

Known fine array
Random values:         (0.6745399522587823, 0.47616297212022757, 0.34117425062278584)
Random values scaled:  (0.6745399522587823, 4.761629721202293e-06, 3.411742506227867e-06)
```

Why would the shape parameter change so dramatically when the only difference in the data is a change in scaling? I would've expected the behavior to be consistent with the FineArr results (no change in shape parameter, and appropriate scaling of location and scale parameters). I've repeated the test in Matlab, but the results there are in line with what I expected (i.e., no change in shape parameter).

Comment: What and where is this **shape parameter**? Can you guide us please?

Comment: @Bazingaa, `gev.fit` returns a tuple of length 3, containing the shape, location and scale parameters (in that order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know why this might be happening. It is possible to pass initial shape parameter estimates when fitting, see the documentation for scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit where it states "Starting value(s) for any shape-characterizing arguments (those not provided will be determined by a call to _fitstart(data)). No default value." Here is some extremely ugly, functional, code using my pyeq3 statistical distribution fitter which internally attempts to use different estimates, fit them, and return the parameters for best nnlf of the different fits. This example code does not show the behavior you observe, and gives the same shape parameters regardless of scaling. You would need to install pyeq3 with "pip3 install pyeq3" to run this code. The pyeq3 code is designed for text input from a web interface on zunzun.com, so hold you nose - here is the example code:

```
import numpy as np

#Set up arrays of values to fit curve to 
sample=np.random.rand(1,30) #Random set of decimal values 
smallVals = sample*1e-5     #Scale to smaller values 

#If the above is not creating different values, this instance of random numbers has:
bugArr = np.array([0.25322987, 0.81952358, 0.94497455, 0.36295543, 0.72272746, 0.49482558,0.65674877, 0.40876558, 0.64952248, 0.23171052, 0.24645658, 0.35359126,0.27578928, 0.24820775, 0.69789187, 0.98876361, 0.22104156,0.40019593,0.0756707,  0.12342556, 0.3601186,  0.54137089,0.43477705, 0.44622486,0.75483338, 0.69766687, 0.1508741,  0.75428996, 0.93706003, 0.1191987])
bugArr_small = bugArr*1e-5

#This array of random numbers gives the same shape parameter regardless 
fineArr = np.array([0.7449611,  0.82376693, 0.32601009, 0.18544293, 0.56779629, 0.30495415,
        0.04670362, 0.88106521, 0.34013959, 0.84598841, 0.24454428, 0.57981437,
        0.57129427, 0.8857514,  0.96254429, 0.64174078, 0.33048637, 0.17124045,
        0.11512589, 0.31884749, 0.48975204, 0.87988863, 0.86898236, 0.83513966,
        0.05858769, 0.25889509, 0.13591874, 0.89106616, 0.66471263, 0.69786708])
fineArr_small = fineArr*1e-5

bugArr_str = ''
for i in range(len(bugArr)):
    bugArr_str += str(bugArr[i]) + '\n'
bugArr_small_str = ''
for i in range(len(bugArr_small)):
    bugArr_small_str += str(bugArr_small[i]) + '\n'
fineArr_str = ''
for i in range(len(fineArr)):
    fineArr_str += str(fineArr[i]) + '\n'
fineArr_small_str = ''
for i in range(len(fineArr_small)):
    fineArr_small_str += str(fineArr_small[i]) + '\n'
import pyeq3

simpleObject_bugArr = pyeq3.IModel.IModel()
simpleObject_bugArr._dimensionality = 1
pyeq3.dataConvertorService().ConvertAndSortColumnarASCII(bugArr_str, simpleObject_bugArr, False)
solver = pyeq3.solverService()
result_bugArr = solver.SolveStatisticalDistribution('genextreme', simpleObject_bugArr.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary['IndependentData'][0], 'nnlf')
simpleObject_bugArr_small = pyeq3.IModel.IModel()
simpleObject_bugArr_small._dimensionality = 1
pyeq3.dataConvertorService().ConvertAndSortColumnarASCII(bugArr_small_str, simpleObject_bugArr_small, False)
solver = pyeq3.solverService()
result_bugArr_small = solver.SolveStatisticalDistribution('genextreme', simpleObject_bugArr_small.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary['IndependentData'][0], 'nnlf')

simpleObject_fineArr = pyeq3.IModel.IModel()
simpleObject_fineArr._dimensionality = 1
pyeq3.dataConvertorService().ConvertAndSortColumnarASCII(fineArr_str, simpleObject_fineArr, False)
solver = pyeq3.solverService()
result_fineArr = solver.SolveStatisticalDistribution('genextreme', simpleObject_fineArr.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary['IndependentData'][0], 'nnlf')

simpleObject_fineArr_small = pyeq3.IModel.IModel()
simpleObject_fineArr_small._dimensionality = 1
pyeq3.dataConvertorService().ConvertAndSortColumnarASCII(fineArr_small_str, simpleObject_fineArr_small, False)
solver = pyeq3.solverService()
result_fineArr_small = solver.SolveStatisticalDistribution('genextreme', simpleObject_fineArr_small.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary['IndependentData'][0], 'nnlf')

print('ba',result_bugArr[1]['fittedParameters'])
print('ba_s',result_bugArr_small[1]['fittedParameters'])
print()
print('fa',result_fineArr[1]['fittedParameters'])
print('fa_s',result_fineArr_small[1]['fittedParameters'])
```